# Why does this variable not set in a setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, settimeout, jquery-events

I have a basic textarea:

```
<textarea id='text_comment'></div>
```

I have this function:

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress', function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
    string = $(this).val();         

         alert(string);
    }, 500);

});
```

It should alert the value that is in the textarea, but it alerts nothing.

I would like it to get the value of the textarea after 500ms, but it doesn't seem to set the variable if it is inside of the `setTimeout` function.

Comment: you're closing the `textarea` with a `div`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

context becomes `window`'s since `setTimeout` is a method of `window`.

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress', function() {

    var el = this;

    setTimeout(function() {
         var string = $(el).val();         

         alert(string);
    }, 500);

});
```

if you save a reference to the el in this manner you can rely on it instead of `this`

And also, you can just use `el.value` since theres no need to wrap it in jQuery and do the exact same thing internally by `.val()`

Comment: great! thank you for the speedy response. Will accept when it lets me

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` changes inside the function passed to setTimeout. Do it like this:

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress', function() {

    var self = this

    setTimeout(function() {
    string = $(self).val();         

         alert(string);
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: Thank you too, your answer was great

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` depends on how the current function has been called. The function you pass to `setTimeout` is a different function to the event handler, so the value of `this` is different.

Make a copy of `this` first.

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress', function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
    string = $(that).val();         
         alert(string);
    }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the callback is not run in the scope of the `keypress` event, but in the global scope `window`.

Copy the reference to a local variable so that it's included in the closure:

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress', function() {

  var element = this;

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var string = $(element).val();         
    alert(string);
  }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

when 'keypress' event is fired, the value of `this` in the function would be `textarea` object. But when the function in `setTimeout` is run (after 500 milliseconds), the value of `this` has been changed to something else (perhaps `window` object)

Change your code to:

```
$('#text_comment').live('keypress', function() {

    var textarea = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
    string = $(textarea).val();         

         alert(string);
    }, 500);

});
```